# iOS: how to load safari to uiwebview on UIViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, webview

I have a controller with UIWebview. I want to load a web page with address bar and navigation bar like safari on my webview.

I use this method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

but it always displays on safari browser.

How can I put a safari on my webview with address bar and navigation bar?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

[_webView loadRequest:request]; //Where _webView is a reference to your webview
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I use your way it doesn't display address bar and navigation bar. How to make they display?